# Optimize a query with left join subquery for search

Tags: php, mysql, join

My database (simplified)

**inv_assets**

```
| id | manufacturer | type | description
| 1  | HP           | 1    | random string
| 2  | Dell         | 4    | test string
```

**inv_location**

```
| id | asset_id | building | room | user | date_moved
| 1  | 1        | main     | 100  | John | 2014-04-01 
| 2  | 1        | main     | 102  | Henry| 2014-04-20
| 3  | 2        | remote   | 200  | Beth | 2014-05-01
| 4  | 2        | main     | 105  | Jim  | 2014-05-30
```

Where each item in the items table will have multiple locations in the locations table depending on how many times the item has been moved.  The most recent date in the locations table would be the current location of the item.

I'm building a search based on this.  It works, but the query takes a long time to complete.  Right now it takes about 35 seconds to execute, but it does seem to return the desired results.

Is there a way to only return the most recent location in the join and make it run faster?

Here is a typical query

```
SELECT `inv_assets`.*, `inv_location`.`location_id`, `inv_location`.`responsible_user` 
FROM (`inv_assets`) 
LEFT JOIN `inv_location` ON inv_location.id = (SELECT inv_location.id FROM inv_location WHERE inv_location.asset_id = inv_assets.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)  
WHERE `location_id` LIKE '%207%'
```

I'm using Codeigniter.  Here is my search function

```
function doadvsearch(){
    $search_terms = array();

    $post_data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    foreach ($post_data as $key => $value){
        if ($value != ''){
            $search_terms[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->db->select('inv_assets.*, inv_location.location_id, inv_location._user');
    $this->db->from('inv_assets');
    $this->db->join('inv_location', 'inv_location.id = (SELECT inv_location.id FROM inv_location WHERE inv_location.asset_id = inv_assets.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)', 'left', FALSE);

    foreach ($search_terms as $skey => $svalue){
        $this->db->or_like($skey, $svalue);
    }

    if (!empty($search_terms)){
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer.  I'd love to share it, but I don't have the reputation to make that happen.  Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Located the solution and wrote it into my CI function

```
function doadvsearch(){
    $search_terms = array();
    $location_fields = array('responsible_user', 'building_id', 'room_no', 'location_id');


    $post_data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    foreach ($post_data as $key => $value){
        if ($value != ''){
            $search_terms[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->db->select('inv_assets.*, lo.location_id, lo.responsible_user');
    $this->db->from('inv_assets');
    $this->db->join('inv_location lo', 'lo.asset_id = inv_assets.id', 'LEFT OUTER', FALSE);
    $this->db->join('inv_location lo2', 'lo2.asset_id = inv_assets.id AND lo.id < lo2.id', 'LEFT OUTER', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('lo2.id IS NULL', NULL, FALSE);

    foreach ($search_terms as $skey => $svalue){
        if (in_array($skey, $location_fields)){
            $skey = "lo.$skey";
        }
        $this->db->or_like($skey, $svalue);
    }

    if (!empty($search_terms)){
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        return array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add an index the column you always use in your table fields inside your database. or you can try $this->db->query(STRAIGHT QUERY); instead of using some functions.

Comment: Indexes are included in the db.  I'm pretty sure using $this->db->query('query text') isn't going to help (from a performance standpoint) over active record.  It's the query that is slow, not the CI code.

Comment: is your id's both indexed in database?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a recursive query, that's the source of the problem. In fact, the subquery is executed once per row of the first query. I'm not sure that could be avoided...

You could use a `GROUP BY` to get better performances.. Ex:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT MAX(date_moved) FROM inv_location AS l 
    WHERE l.asset_id = assets.id)
    AS last_date_moved 
FROM inv_assets AS assets
```

Comment: This doesn't address the join.  There are items in both tables that need to be included.

Comment: I'm selecting all the data from the inv_assets table, and adding a field with the last date. You need also the last known location? If you need that, the only other option left is denormalizing the information, decupling the last known location into the assets table. This is not optimal, but the subquery is the only elegant solution to your problem, hence the performance decrease.